# javafx combobox of object how to get selection

Tags: javafx

I have a comboBox i have populated using student from an arraylist:

```
            ComboBox<Student> comboBox = new ComboBox();
                for (int i = 0; i < control.getSize(); i++) {
                
                comboBox.getItems().add(control.returnElement(i));
```

How do I now on a Button press know which Student object the user has selected so I can pass it into a method, I might be able to work with just knowing the index too

I tried it like this but it gives me an error:

```
Student studentSelect = comboBox.getItems();
```

Comment: _obviously I did that_ well, to me it looks like just the contrary: simply searching for "select" on the java doc page of combobox comes up with several sentences/references to api with the notion of selection (plus making the connection to the combo's value)

Answer (score 1):

with `comboBox.getValue();` or `comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();`

Comment: does the getValue return an object? In this case i need a full student object returned.

Comment: yes , it returns an object  ,in your case is Student studentSelect = comboBox.getValue();

Comment: @Milan The `getValue()` method is defined to return `T`, a generic type parameter defined at the class level. So if you have a `ComboBox<Student>` then `getValue()` will return a `Student` (or `null` if there is no value). [This is documented](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue()) in `ComboBoxBase` (the superclass of `ComboBox`). If you wanted, you could instead go through the [selection model](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#selectionModelProperty).